# What are the UI blocking thread operation in Java or Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is there a documentation list of all UI blocking operation in Java or Kotlin like `InputStream.read()`? Or other way to identify blocking operation without needing to run the project?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. Hence writing async code in java is borderline impossible. In fact, loading any class can theoretically be blocking (classes are loaded the first time you use them, and it involves 'disk access', though especially on android the odds this is going to meaningfully slow stuff down is insignificant. But, theoretically, it's blocking). Fortunately, use common sense, it tends to be obvious. Any file access, any network access, any DB access, and any operation whose name includes 'sleep' or 'wait' - that blocks.

Comment: That is what I am doing, I am treating file writing as UI blocking already but this could make a code smell at some point thus I wonder if we have a curated list. Does classes that has `write` method is consider as potential blocking thread as well like `FileOutputStream` or the `OutputStream` from `ContentResolver`?

Comment: Typed three big comments and realised I should have just posted it as an answer so I'm not spamming

Comment: In Java you can assume that everything throwing `IOException` may be potentially blocking. But this is oversimplification. As others said: you need to use common sense.

Comment: I was hoping to get a documentation that at least explains further about these UI blocking method like from this one: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/blocking-methods-in-java/. I guess there's no such documentation that exist.

Answer (score 4):

All code runs on a thread, and that thread can't run the next bit of code until it's finished with the current bit. With things like Android, the main thread runs a loop where it does tasks like updating the UI, laying out and drawing `View`s, responding to touch events etc, and calling lifecycle methods like `onResume` or things like click listener functions. If the code in any of that stuff takes "too long", it's basically holding up the loop and delaying all the other things that need to happen. That's what "blocking" is, when the amount of time a thing (potentially) takes is significant, and can meaningfully delay other stuff that needs to happen.

Basically it depends what you're doing. If it can take a "significant" amount of time, don't do it on the main/UI thread or you'll block UI stuff from happening in a timely fashion - or worse, get an Application Not Responding warning popup because you've frozen the app for several seconds. Ideally the UI should be able to update every 16ms (60fps) so any slow tasks that would make it miss that target should be avoided. IO and networking definitely shouldn't be on the main thread. You just have to be aware of what you're doing - e.g. is the `write` method going to a file, or a buffer in memory?

There's actually a `@WorkerThread` annotation in Android that basically means "you should call this method from a non-UI thread" and the linter can warn you if it thinks you're not doing that, but I'm not sure how much stuff uses it. Some bug-checking plugins might be able to spot that kind of behaviour too. You can use [StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode) as well to warn you when you're doing IO and networking on the main thread, but that involves running your app - not a bad way to identify problems though!